# If I deploy my web application to Windows Azure, do I need a traditional host?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I just started to read about this new technology...

Does someone have some knowledge about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/azure/howdoesitwork.mspx

> Windows Azure is a cloud services
>   operating system that serves as the
>   development, service hosting, and
>   service management environment for the
>   Azure Services Platform. Windows Azure
>   provides developers with on-demand
>   compute and storage to host and manage
>   web applications on the internet
>   through Microsoft data centers.

So in summary, no you do not need a traditional web host if you used Microsoft's Azure. Note also that it is still only in Community Technology Preview and it isn't something you should be thinking about right now, IMHO.

Comment: Asp.net MVC was only a preview when stackoverflow build this site so .. you know ... but its IMHO too .. :-)

Comment: @Moran: Jeff certainly went against best practices using a beta for production and it worked out for him, but that is not a good reason to negate the best practice.

Comment: Stackoverflow may be production software with ads, but it is still beta itself. Then again, ASP.NET MVC was probably pretty stable. Jeff used to work for Vertigo and they had pretty close relations with MS.